# Complex conditions on Eloquent Joins

Tags: mysql, join, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I'm looking to use Eloquent to output some data from our database, but the database can vary.

Below is an illustration of my database tables

**Webservice Tags:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | webservice_tag        | webservice_name | blog_id |
==========================================================
| 1  | TEST, TESSST, TES     | Test Service    | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | OPTION, OPT, EXAMPLE  | Example Service | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | ANOTHER, ANO, THER    | Another Service | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Blog Post:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | title                         | blog_id | tag     |
==========================================================
| 1  | Blog Title 1                  | 1       | THER    |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Blog Title 2                  | 1       | TES     |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | Blog Title 3                  | 1       | ANOTHER |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

So here, we have two tables. Blog Posts and Web-service Tags.

Our blog posts are populated by a number of web-services from a number of different providers. Test Service, Example Service and Another Service for example. However, these web-services are very inconsistent; they'll send over a combination of tags, and no two posts are guaranteed to be the same.

So, we've created a table called Webservice Tags which is designed to log each of these occurrances. This way we can identify that (in the examples) Blog Title 3 was sent by Another Service, Blog Title 2 was sent by Test Service etc.

I'm developing reports to show how many posts we get from each of our web services. So for each blog post, I need to identify the web service and get the web service name that's associated with it. We have multiple blogs, each with their own web services (some may share a tag), so this report needs to be isolated to each individual blog.

Here's the query in Eloquent:

```
$query = DB::table('blog_posts')
    ->join('webservice_tags', function($join) use ($blog) {
        $join->on('blog_posts.tag', '=', 'webservice_tags.webservice_tag')
        ->where('webservice_tags.blog_id', '=', $blog->id);
    })
    ->addSelect('webservice_tags.webservice_name AS name')
    ->addSelect(DB::raw("COUNT(blog_posts.id) AS count"))
    ->where('blog_posts.blog_id', '=', $blog->id)
    ->groupBy('webservice_tags.webservice_name')
    ->get();
```

This query was fine whilst the Webservice sent a consistent tag. Now however there are different tags per web service and this report needs to count them all equally.

Here's my amendment, but it's not working as expected:

```
->join('webservice_tags', function($join) use ($blog) {
    $join->on('blog_posts.tag', 'LIKE', DB::raw('CONCAT("%", webservice_tags.webservice_tag, "%")'))
    ->where('webservice_tags.blog_id', '=', $blog->id);
})
```

I'm not getting any matches in the query through this method.

The query aims to join any field to the SELECT where the blog_posts.tag is within the comma separated list of webservice_tags.

Is there a way to do this more effectively?

**Explanation on the `blog_id` relationship**

This system manages multiple blogs, as well as the posts within those blogs. A webservice may be applicable to one blog, but not the other, which is why the `blog_id` is associated witih webservices as well as the individual posts. There are things like commission percentages that are associated with a webservice, and Test Webservice may offer 10% for Blog A, and 12% for Blog B, so they are essentially separate.

Comment: I have no idea about what you're asking, but have an upvote for the best formulated question I've seen today. cheers!

Comment: Thanks! It essentially boils down to using wildcards and 'LIKE' statements in a join condition. I need TEST, TESSST and TES to increment the count for Test Service, instead of treating them all individually.

Comment: May I ask what actually is `blog_id`? It seems like it's not the blog post id since you already have `id` for it. It's also a bit strange that `blog_id` appears in webservice tags as well.

Comment: @Unnawut it's a system that manages multiple blogs, as well as the posts within those blogs. A webservice may be applicable to one blog, but not the other, which is why the `blog_id` is associated witih webservices as well as the individual posts. There are things like commission percentages that are associated with a webservice, and Test Webservice may offer 10% for Blog A, and 12% for Blog B, so they are essentially separate. I'll drop this into the question as well, to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Quickest/crude solution:

The reason you do not see any result is because of this:

```
$join->on('blog_posts.tag', 'LIKE', DB::raw('CONCAT("%", webservice_tags.webservice_tag, "%")'))
```

which translates to:

```
INNER JOIN `webservice_tags`
   ON `blog_posts`.`tag` LIKE CONCAT("%", webservice_tags.webservice_tag, "%")
```

This tries to match `blog_posts`.`tag` that has values like `%ANOTHER, ANO, THER%`.

So let's say `blog_posts.tag` is "ANOTHER" and `webservice_tags.webservice_tag` is "ANOTHER, ANO, THER". Rather than matching "ANOTHER", the database is trying to match values like these:

```
ANOTHER    !=    FOOANOTHER, ANO, THER
ANOTHER    !=    ANOTHER, ANO, THERBAR
ANOTHER    !=    FOOANOTHER, ANO, THERBAR
```

Which is the reason why you are not getting any results. You will need to swap the columns around, like this:

```
$join->on('webservice_tags.webservice_tag', 'LIKE', DB::raw('CONCAT("%", blog_posts.tag, "%")'))
```

---

## Longer solution:

I'm just going to throw my idea here. These are some points that come into my mind when thinking about this:

- Tag <-> Web Service mapping is stored as a string when it is actually a set of data. That makes it hard to search and hard to perform queries on it. I like to break them down into two or more tables. This is called [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Don't ask me which level it is, I never understood the technical description for them. :D
- Since you mentioned that a web service can have many tags, but some tags can also be shared by different web services, we will need a pivot table to handle this many-to-many relationship.
- When aggregating, I like to start from top down. So I write queries starting from webservices, then work my way down to blog posts. This is the opposite of your example.
- I'm ignoring `blog_id` columns in webservices table for now since I don't quite understand yet what they do.

So first I would actually try to normalize the tables first into webservices, webservice_tags, tags, and blog_posts, like this:

**webservices:**

```
-------------------------
| id  | webservice_name |
=========================
| 1   | Test Service    |
-------------------------
| 2   | Example Service |
-------------------------
| 3   | Another Service |
-------------------------
```

**webservice_tags:**

```
------------------------------------------
| id | tag_name          | webservice_id |
==========================================
| 1  | TEST              | 1             |
------------------------------------------
| 2  | TESSST            | 1             |
------------------------------------------
| 3  | TES               | 1             |
------------------------------------------
| 4  | OPTION            | 2             |
------------------------------------------
| 5  | OPT               | 2             |
------------------------------------------
| 6  | EXAMPLE           | 2             |
------------------------------------------
| 7  | ANOTHER           | 3             |
------------------------------------------
| 8  | ANO               | 3             |
------------------------------------------
| 9  | THER              | 3             |
------------------------------------------
| 10 | FOO               | NULL          |
------------------------------------------
| 11 | BAR               | NULL          |
------------------------------------------
```

*Note that I'm using `tag_name` in the pivot table above for the sake of readability. I guess it would be better to use `tag_id` instead.*

**tags:**

```
--------------------------
| id | tag_name          |
==========================
| 1  | TEST              |
--------------------------
| 2  | TESSST            |
--------------------------
| 3  | TES               |
--------------------------
| 4  | OPTION            |
--------------------------
| 5  | OPT               |
--------------------------
| 6  | EXAMPLE           |
--------------------------
| 7  | ANOTHER           |
--------------------------
| 8  | ANO               |
--------------------------
| 9  | THER              |
--------------------------
| 10 | FOO               |
--------------------------
| 11 | BAR               |
--------------------------
```

**blog_posts:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| id | title                         | blog_id | tag_name |
===========================================================
| 1  | Blog Title 1                  | 1       | THER     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Blog Title 2                  | 1       | TES      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | Blog Title 3                  | 1       | ANOTHER  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now to get a report of how many blog posts are created by each web service, we can do this with a join query.
In this case a QueryBuilder query would give a better performance since we want to know just the aggregates, not the actual database models:

```
$report = DB::table('webservices')
    ->leftJoin('webservice_tags', 'webservice_tags.webservice_id', '=', 'webservices.id')
    ->leftJoin('tags', 'tags.tag_name', '=', 'webservices_tags.tag_name')
    ->leftJoin('blog_posts', 'blog_posts.tag_name', '=', 'tags.tag_name')
    ->where('blog_posts.blog_id', '=', $blog->id)
    ->select(['webservices.webservice_name', DB::raw('COUNT(`blog_posts.id`) as `num_posts`')])
    ->groupBy('webservices.id')
    ->get();
```

You would now get a report of how many blog posts were created by each web service, for all web services.

One note is that, since you mentioned a web service may share tags, and you are identifying web service <-> blog posts via tags,
you cannot 100% accurately determine the origin web service because you won't know for sure which web service set that tag for that post.

---

Extra: You might notice that I also added FOO and BAR to the Webservice Tags.
This would help in case, like you said that web services are "very inconsistent", new tags would be added to your database.
You could also query them and generate a report easily to find out which tag hasn't been mapped yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was worried that normalisation was the way forward, and I may have to take you up on this advice if there is no other way. You see, I was hoping to do it without affecting the actual database as this was pretty much all set up by the person who originally designed the system. Although I do have scope to change what I need to, I was hoping to preserve this feature as much as possible; changing the tables will inevitably involve changing associated Models and Controllers as well, increasing the man-hours of the fix. I'll give it a go and let you know of the outcome. :)

Comment: Ah sorry for answering something that's probably obvious to you already. IMHO, I would normalize it anyway if I have to maintain/extend this system in the future. I would be afraid leaving the DB structure this way would cost more man-hours in the medium/long-run. Anyhow, I'm going to try out the code in your question with your current table structure and see why it is not returning results then.

Comment: @DanHanly I've added a crude solution on top of my answer which should solve why you are not seeing any results.

Comment: wish I could upvote you twice! I've accepted your answer and it works very well. I appreciate you tailoring your solution to my situation!